# Can a single crystal oscillator drive both an MCU and an ADC?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, oscillator, clock

My STM32G491 design uses an 8MHz crystal for the HSE clock based on the reference design. My design also has a ΔΣ ADC that requires an 8.192MHz LVCMOS clock signal. I do not have any synchronization requirements between the MCU and ADC clocks.

- Is it advisable to use the same clock source for both the MCU and ADC to simplify component count?
- Are buffers required to manage the fanout from an oscillator such as the [ECS-2520MVLC](https://ecsxtal.com/store/pdf/ECS-2520MVLC.pdf) to drive two devices?
- Is it better to use a separate oscillator for each IC?

Comment: The oscillator can certainly drive two loads. Best to add small series resistor to each. If the ADC sample rate isn't critical (i.e. doesn't require exactly 8.192MHz) then you should be fine.

Comment: The ADC does need 8.192MHz to get nice integral sample rates, so I am proposing to drive the MCU with this clock instead of 8MHz. The PLL can generate a max clock of 139.264MHz from that which is a strange value, but should be fine for my purposes.

Comment: 1) One oscillator is better than two.  2) Buffer the output of the oscillator to each chip (2 buffers).  3) Series resistors after each buffer (like td127 said).

Comment: Put a crystal on the micro and then use the Micro's MCO output to clock the ADC.